# About 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()'

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I'm making board with spring framework and I have a issue.

I want to send Parameter 'Id' to Controller with Ajax

```
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "${contextPath}/checkId?id=" + input_id.value;
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
              if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                //var checkId = "${checkID}";
                
                var checkId = xhr.responseText;
                
                console.log("success");
                
                if(checkId === "" || checkId === undefined){
                    form_action.submit();
                    alert("Welcome!");
                    window.close();
                }
                else {
                    alert("ID exists");
                } 
                
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
              }
            };
            xhr.send();
```

And Controller is

```
    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value="/checkId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String checkId(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        
        String isIdExists = memberService.checkId(id); 
        //String isIdExistSts = String.valueOf(isIdExists); 
        System.out.println(isIdExists);
        request.setAttribute("checkID", isIdExists);
        //return "forward:/signUp";
        return "/signUp";
    }
```

but this errors is occurred

[image]

What is problem? could you help?

Comment: did you check you backend code as it is 404 from server

Comment: thank you for your answer. I changed 'return "/signUp";' -> return "forward:/signUp";'' of controller and it works. but I faced another issue. var checkId = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText); takes parameter all of html source 
instead of 'request.setAttribute("checkID", isIdExists);' like this, '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sing Up</titl   ' ...

Comment: not getting your question

Comment: thanks . I'll try When I have a time.